# Как вывести изображение категорий в category_list.tpl opencart 2.1.0.2?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.0

В контролере category.php
на 189 строке данный код

```
$category_total = $this->model_catalog_category->getTotalCategories();

$results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($filter_data);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $data['categories'][] = array(
        'category_id' => $result['category_id'],
        'name'        => $result['name'],
        'sort_order'  => $result['sort_order'],
        'edit'        => $this->url->link('catalog/category/edit', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&category_id=' . $result['category_id'] . $url, 'SSL'),
        'delete'      => $this->url->link('catalog/category/delete', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&category_id=' . $result['category_id'] . $url, 'SSL')
    );
}
```

если добавить в масив

```
'image' => $result['image'],
```

то выводит пустоту хотя в других шаблонах таким же способом достаются изображение для главной.
Как достать изображения для шаблона category_list.tpl в админке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо редактирования шаблона вывода и контроллера категории нужно отредактировать запрос в базу данных в модели:

**/admin/model/catalog/category.php**

Немного правим sql-запрос в функции **getCategories()**

Добавляем выборку для изображения **c1.image** из таблицы **oc_category**:

```
$sql = "SELECT cp.category_id AS category_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name ORDER BY cp.level SEPARATOR '&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;') AS name, c1.image, c1.parent_id, c1.sort_order FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c1 ON (cp.category_id = c1.category_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c2 ON (cp.path_id = c2.category_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd1 ON (cp.path_id = cd1.category_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd2 ON (cp.category_id = cd2.category_id) WHERE cd1.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND cd2.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";
```

В итоге в **$result['image']** у нас будет храниться ссылка на изображение.